# How do I set LC_CTYPE to C?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, locale

I'm trying to set `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_COLLATE` to `C`, while keeping the remaining `LC_*` set to `"en_US.UTF-8"`.  I'm working inside an Ubuntu 16.04 VM.  My current environment has:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

and

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
<some other locales>
POSIX
```

When I RUN

```
$ sudo update-locale LC_CTYPE=C
```

LC_CTYPE doesn't get set

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I *can* see the default has been written to the file

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale
# File generated by update-locale
LC_CTYPE=C
```

but when I `source ~/.bashrc` or restart the VM, it still doesn't show `"C"`. There also isn't an `LC_CYTPE` variable (which I don't understand).

```
$ echo $LC_CTYPE
<empty string here>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should change environment variables in Dockerfile (and build new image), not in already running container as it's useless.

Comment: The same thing happens in an Ubuntu 16.04 VM.

Comment: Sourcing `~/.bashrc` won't normally re-read the global profile. This is more suitable for askubuntu.com anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by executing `unset LC_ALL`.  Once I did that, `export LC_CTYPE=C` worked.

`LC_ALL` is an override.  When it's set, it takes precedence over the other LC_* env variables and the `locale` command honors that. I found many pages that stated that this variable is usually not set by default.

Answer (score 0):

the manpage for locale(7) explains how the categories are assigned values:

If the second argument to setlocale(3) is an empty string, "",
for the default locale, it is determined using the following
steps:

```
   1. If there is a non-null environment variable LC_ALL, the value
      of LC_ALL is used.

   2. If an environment variable with the same name as one of the
      categories above exists and is non-null, its value is used for
      that category.

   3. If there is a non-null environment variable LANG, the value of
      LANG is used.
```